# Scoring on Google Sheets with IF/AND statements

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I made a bracket for Game of Thrones for work that I want to have auto-score. So, if Mackenzie!B3="x" and Results!B3="x" then it will +1 to their score. But if Mackenzie!E3="x" and Results!E3="(blank)" then it will -1 their score but give them a point if they both have "x" as a value. I'm not sure how much sense that makes so I made a copy of the sheet here for reference:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1zvkolDZTYEGHsCYgZFRKgsy522j05sf1QPW7p9hkYUs/edit?usp=sharing

I've tried a few ways of doing `IF` statements and `MATCH` functions. I would really appreciate any help you can give me on this as I'll likely run things like this again in the future.

Comment: in which sheet you want that name+score?

Comment: @player0 I just added a score sheet to the doc!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

paste in **C3** cell and drag down:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SUM(
 SUM(IF(INDIRECT(B3&"!B3:B37")<>"", IF(INDIRECT(B3&"!B3:B37")=Results!B$3:B$37, 1, ), )),
 SUM(IF(INDIRECT(B3&"!C3:C37")<>"", IF(INDIRECT(B3&"!C3:C37")=Results!C$3:C$37, 1, ), )),
 SUM(IF(INDIRECT(B3&"!E3:E37")<>"", IF(INDIRECT(B3&"!E3:E37")=Results!E$3:E$37, 1, -1), )))
 +SUMPRODUCT(
 IF(INDIRECT(B3&"!B40")<>"", IF(INDIRECT(B3&"!B40")=Results!B$40, 1, ), )+
 IF(INDIRECT(B3&"!B41")<>"", IF(INDIRECT(B3&"!B41")=Results!B$41, 2, ), )+
 IF(INDIRECT(B3&"!B42")<>"", IF(INDIRECT(B3&"!B42")=Results!B$42, 4, ), )))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: actually, I think this may be a bit off. If I mark Tormund as dead you can see under "ross" that he gets two points which should only happen if I mark Tormund dead and he becomes a white walker. If you see at the top right of the sheets there is an explanation of how the scoring works if that helps explain it a bit.